# TypeError: fakeClass is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, web-component, babeljs, webpack-2, custom-element

I'm getting this error while attempting to do a simple custom-element using webpack.

My setup:

```
<script src="/custom-elements.min.js"></script>
<script src="/native-shim.js"></script>
export default class TodoApp extends HTMLElement {
    constructor () {
        super();
        console.log('CONSTRUCT');
    }
}
```

The error happens on line 98 of native-shim:

```
window.HTMLElement = function() {
    if (!browserConstruction) {
        const tagname = tagnameByConstructor.get(this.constructor);
        const fakeClass = nativeGet.call(window.customElements, tagname);

        // Make sure that the fake constructor doesn't call back to this constructor
        userConstruction = true;
        const instance = new (fakeClass)();
        return instance;
    }
    // Else do nothing. This will be reached by ES5-style classes doing
    // HTMLElement.call() during initialization
    browserConstruction = false;
};
```

"tagname" is undefined.

I've tried different versions of babel, including "latest". I've tried changing the order of the shims and excluding the native shim.

Answer (score 1):

According to the error message it's because there's no tag name.

You should define one with, for example:

```
customElements.define( 'todo-app', TodoApp)
```